# Excel Power Pivot - When Pasting Data Decimal Separator is lost?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a problem - when I copy data from an Excel Sheet and I paste that same data into a Power Pivot Window - the decimal separators are lost - but the cents are not - giving me a very large number?
For example, R1,500.55 will be shown as R150,055

[image]

Comment: What are your Windows Regional Settings for decimal and thousands separator?  Are the values in your original data numbers or text?

Comment: Good day, I have tried several number formats but right now i have it as follows for both numbers and currency: Decimal Symbol is a dot "." and Digit Grouping Symbol is one blank space " ". I also tried it with a Digit Grouping Symbol of a "," comma. In South Africa our Decimal Symbol must be a point "."

Comment: Frequently, the type of issue you describe is related to the data in the imported file having different decimal and thousands separator than **Windows Regional Settings** (not the Excel number format) in the destination computer.  Most import routines can adjust for this. I've not seen a circumstance such as you describe, where the number is OK in Excel, but changes in Power Pivot.  But perhaps [Power Pivot, decimal separator error](https://powerbloggerbi.com/2016/11/08/power-pivot-decimal-separator-error/) might be useful.

Comment: And ;yes, I know I'm grasping at straws here, since you write that you are pasting from an Excel sheet, but that would imply that Power Pivot and Excel are handling separators differently.

Comment: Hi Ron, no this is all good input (grasping at straws). So I found two solutions. 1) highlight and find/replace "." with ";" then copy and paste into power pivot, but then I have to create a new measure in powerpivot using SUBSTITUTE(Field, ";",".") then change format to currency and it works.

Comment: Alternatively, I have to close the workbook and open another and use the import from other sources - pick Excel File - pick the sheets and import that way which seems to handle the "." decimal point better.  P.S I manually typed in data into Excel so it is not coming frmo a funny CSV